# Can a firefox extension change in what order it is called at startup?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

[In what order do Firefox extensions get initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620422/in-what-order-do-firefox-extensions-get-initialised) covers how Firefox extensions are usually called during startup (order of install).
I'm wondering if there is an official way for an extension to change that, in particular to say it wants to go near the end (and while we are at it near the start). Similar to a priority flag seen in may other plugin approaches.

Comment: The important information missing in your question: what are we talking about? Still browser window overlays or really extension initialization on startup? Or maybe the order in which overlays get to run their JavaScript code? Or maybe even initialization of restartless extensions? I tried to give a general answer but without giving us any details you cannot expect a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the answer is "no" - the order in which extensions apply can be considered "random" (I sincerely doubt that it really is "in order of installation"). But it still depends on what you want to do.

If you want your XPCOM component to become active during startup, there is a number of [observer notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications). Typically, extensions listen to the `profile-after-change` notification. However, you might also choose to listen to `profile-do-change` and `final-ui-startup`, depending on what your extension wants to do.

If we are talking about browser window overlays, there isn't much you can influence there. However, you can still choose whether you want your overlay to apply to `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` or to an overlay URL that is applied to this window. The latter is in particular useful if you want your overlay to apply after the overlay of another extension that you know must be present.

Comment: So it sounds like overlays are applied before final-ui-startup. Or perhaps I could use sessionstore-windows-restored to ensure they are all loaded?  
And the trick of overlaying over another one sounds really promising.  So I could put my overlay on chrome://someext/content/someext-browser-overlay.xul and my overlay would not be called until after someext-browser-overlay.xul is loaded?  
And I can obviously use a combo also just in case someext-browser-overlay.xul is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard Firefox manifest does not include any support for controlling the load order relative to any other extension. The choice of extension load order is essentially arbitrary and is entirely determined by the Firefox instance in a broadly speaking not-at-all-well-documented fashion.